# PhpStorm: annotation for inherited method return type?

Tags: annotations, phpstorm, intellisense

Using a Behat sub-context class I need to call a method from the main context, e.g. `$this->getMainContext()->fooBar()`. PhpStorm quite reasonably warns me that `fooBar()` doesn't exist, because it expects `getMainContext()` to return an `ExtendedContextInterface`, not my concrete `FeatureContext`.

Is there a way to annotate my sub-class to tell PhpStorm that `getMainContext()` actually returns my concrete class?

One solution is to override `getMainContext()` just to have a method on which to add my own PHPDoc, thus specifying a different return type, but adding a method just to get nicer code sense in an IDE is horrid.

BTW, I know this is all a bit hacky and that theoretically my sub-context shouldn't depend upon my main context having a particular concrete implementation; in reality though Behat doesn't make that practical.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the standard @method annotation for the class works:

```
 /**
  * @method FeatureContext getMainContext()
  */
 class SubContext extends BehatContext
 {
     public function foo()
     {
          $this->getMainContext()->bar();
     }
 }
```

Comment: In the case that someone needs it here is the spec http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.method.pkg.html

Comment: I have almost the same problem except not with a method but a class variable, but I don't think there is a solution. My class (itself derived from a base class) assigns to a base-class member a type which is a sub-class of the type defined in the base class, and I can't figure out how to tell the IDE.

Comment: @AndyClaw Surely you shouldn't need to? If the object you're assigning extends the type the base class specifies then its public API should be the same as that base type's, no?

Comment: Solution found! You can use "magic properties" above the class definition. Looks like "@property". @RichardTurner The child class typically has new functions that are not defined in the parent. The child class is more of an extension of the base, not just an implementation.